# Will my fingerprints be taken when my hands are swabbed for explosives at the airport?

Tags: southeast-europe

When they take a swab of your hands using either the scanner or the paper procedure, do they fingerprint us in the process?thanks

Comment: Do you mean the swab used for explosives (and sometimes drugs) detection at airport security discussed in [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/70810/my-hands-were-scanned-by-a-strange-device-during-a-security-check-at-the-airport)? If so, no. Those machines don't have anything to do with fingerprints. If you mean something else, please tell us what you're describing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Zach Lipton, I thought with all the technology today they could take fingerprints as well when they would swab our hands.

Comment: Unfortunately (or fortunately, depending on your POV) that technology is as yet [insufficiently advanced](https://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/a/arthurccl101182.html).

Comment: As others have said, if you're referring to the wand attachment that usually has a ball or some other object on the end that is rolled across your palm and then inserted into a machine, it's just looking for certain chemical traces.

Comment: Close votes are baffling. The question is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 2):

No, they don't take your fingerprints in the process. They swab your hands with a wet paper and put it inside an explosive detecting machine.

Source: getting swabbed many times.

Answer (score 1):

I have been swabbed for explosives many times in many countries, and my fingerprints were never taken. In fact, I don't think they ever swabbed my fingertips, and it was only the palm of the hand that was swabbed.